# Angular 8: Prevent loading global stylesheet in lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, sass

Here's my problem: I have some style rules set in my global `styles.scss` file. All of the codebase is in app.module. I'm trying to create a lazy-loaded module but someone has globally overridden some angular material styles which are causing problems for components in my lazy module. Removing these overridden rules is not an option as that would cause some widgets in app.module to break.

Let's say I create a new file called `exclude.scss`, and put these rules in that file. Is there any way to configure it so that that app.module still consumes `exclude.scss` but lazy.module does not? Putting it in angular.json styles array would still result in the same output.

To reiterate, I do not want to *add* some rules to my lazy-loaded module, I want a config that *removes* some global rules. A config in which app.module can still use those rules but lazy module does not have to.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

The styles being overridden are from angular material forms:

```
.cdk-global-overlay-wrapper,
.cdk-overlay-container {
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

I know it's a bad pattern, that's why I need to get rid of it. Thing is, these classes don't behave like normal, user-added classes, so a lot of possible approaches won't work.

Comment: You could try encapsulating the rules to exclude with a higher selector, e.g. `:not(.lazy) { /*all rules to exclude here*/}`, and set `lazy` class to `body` from your lazy module's routes

Comment: @David Thanks. That's a good idea and would have worked for most cases. But the styles in question are material. So this won't work. Please see edit.

Comment: You can add classes to overlays if I'm not mistaken. That way could could target specific material components?

Answer (score 0):

Work Flow the `style.scss` in Angular application is root first and then lazy-loaded module,
you can change the `@import` libraries for example

in your global style sheet

`@import Firststylesheet.scss

@import Secondstylesheet.scss

@import Thirdtstylesheet.scss`

whatever you import on the third style sheet will be used

in case of a lazy-loaded module .. it should append your style sheet on the header after the global style sheet.

another way is you can use `@extend`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it's the 1st and 2nd sheets that are overwritten. Third one wins.

Comment: `To reiterate, I do not want to add some rules to my lazy-loaded module, I want a config that removes some global rules. A config in which app.module can still use those rules but lazy module does not have to.` ---> to answer you this part .. you can use forRoot() function in your lazyloaded module, just like bootstrap to use config .. hope that helps